# Why am I getting invalide XML from JSON?

Tags: json, xml, org.json

Here is my code (json is a String):

```
String xml = XML.toString(new JSONObject(json));
```

JSON:

```
{
    "components": {
        "header": "generic",
        "body": "generic",
        "footer": "watchlist"
    },
    "featuredArticle": {
        "title": "Test title",
        "text": "test text."
    },
    "header": {
        "ref": ""
    },
    "body": {
        "ref": ""
    },
    "footer": {
        "ref": ""
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<components>
    <footer>watchlist</footer>
    <header>generic</header>
    <body>generic</body>
</components>
<footer>
    <ref />
</footer>
<header>
    <ref />
</header>
<featuredArticle>
    <text>test text.</text>
    <title>Test title</title>
</featuredArticle>
<body>
    <ref />
</body>
```

When I validate the JSON in text mate it passes, but the XML does not.

Comment: where is `XML` from? what package does it belong to

Comment: You don't have any surrounding tags around your XML. All the sections are at the top-level

Comment: @quidproquo `org.json.XML`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A valid XML must have a [root element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element). Your example does not have one.

Try the following JSON (added root element `"data"`):

```json
{
    "data": {
        "components": {
            "header": "generic",
            "body": "generic",
            "footer": "watchlist"
        },
        "featuredArticle": {
            "title": "Test title",
            "text": "test text."
        },
        "header": {
            "ref": ""
        },
        "body": {
            "ref": ""
        },
        "footer": {
            "ref": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the XML markup language that is not valid, you just need a root element holding the elements, try here :http://www.xmlvalidation.com/index.php?id=1&L=2 
and verify that the xml will be ok until you close the component node...

[image]

```
<root>
    all the xml content
</root>
```

Comment: no. look at the json structure, the xml mimics it pretty well.

Comment: @njzk2 you are correct, I will correct the mistake... Thanks